# Adding static SQL tables and their data doesn't work since TYPO3 6.2

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I need pre-filled table for an extension which I have developed. Since TYPO3 version 6.2 the import of static SQL data doesn't work anymore. I've nothing changed on the `ext_tables_static+adt.sql` file, so I'm wondering what's going wrong.

Is there another way to import table data while installing? The Core API for TYPO3 6.2 still recommends using `ext_tables_static+adt.sql` (see http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/singlehtml/). Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/64119

In general `ext_tables_static+adt.sql` is imported only during the very first install, otherwise you need to handle it yourself. For this you need to use `class.ext_update.php` - [@see the API](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/singlehtml/)

Take a look into `static_info_tables` ext for usage sample.

Tip: dirty solution  useful i.e. during development and testing of the ext is removing `extensionDataImport` row for your ext from `sys_registry` table and reinstalling the ext.